# Wrap Case in Group By statement MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sum up table below into one line with 3Month, 6Month, 9Month, and so on but stuck with mysql error. I did lookup other similar posts and replaced GROUP BY alias with full case but still says contains nonaggregated column. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
mysql> SELECT ith.ItemCode, ith.TransactionDate, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) AS Date_Diff,
    ->  (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 0_90_Days,
    ->  (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 91_180_Days,
    ->  (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 181 AND 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 181_270_Days,
    ->  (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) > 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS Over_270_Days
    ->
    -> FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith, ci_item i
    -> WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
    -> AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
    -> AND ith.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
    -> AND i.TotalQuantityOnHand > 0
    -> AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
    -> GROUP BY ith.ItemCode, ith.TransactionDate, ith.TransactionQty
    ->
    -> ORDER BY ith.TransactionDate ASC;
+----------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| ItemCode | TransactionDate | Date_Diff | 0_90_Days | 91_180_Days | 181_270_Days | Over_270_Days |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|   512619 | 2018-03-19      |       220 |         0 |           0 |         1200 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-05-10      |       168 |         0 |        3600 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-05-11      |       167 |         0 |         600 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-06-15      |       132 |         0 |        3600 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-06-26      |       121 |         0 |        2400 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-07-23      |        94 |         0 |        2400 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-07-26      |        91 |         0 |        1200 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-09-10      |        45 |      1200 |           0 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-09-10      |        45 |      2400 |           0 |            0 |             0 |
|   512619 | 2018-10-16      |         9 |      1092 |           0 |            0 |             0 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

And this is what I've tried..

```
SELECT ith.ItemCode, ith.TransactionCode, i.TotalQuantityOnHand, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate),
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 0_90_Days,
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 91_180_Days,
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 181 AND 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 181_270_Days,
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) > 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS Over_270_Days,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 3m_total,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 6m_total,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 181 AND 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 9m_total,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) > 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS Over9m_total

FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith, ci_item i
WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
AND ith.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
AND i.TotalQuantityOnHand > 0
AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
GROUP BY ith.ItemCode,
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END),
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END),
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 181 AND 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END),
 (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) > 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END)

ORDER BY ith.TransactionDate ASC
```

The error code would return

```
#1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mas90.ith.TransactionDate' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

And this is the output I am looking for..

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| ItemCode | 0_90_Days | 91_180_Days | 181_270_Days | Over_270_Days |
+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|   512619 |      4692 |       13800 |         1200 |             0 |
+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please add error description in your question

Comment: could you show your desired output (and explicitly describe what order you are expecting the output in)

Comment: Error code added thanks!

Comment: Also added desired output!

Comment: Some time ago a had a problem that looks similar. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080167/select-group-by-function-result

Comment: BTW: Please use an explicit JOIN.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Awesome thanks Robert Kock! After some trials and errors I was able to wrap CASE in FROM and apply alias to GROUP BY. You just saved my day thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Robert Kock I was able to solve this with query below.

```
SELECT ith.ItemCode, TEST1.total, TEST2.0_90_Days, TEST3.91_180_Days, TEST4.181_270_Days, TEST5.Over_270_Days

FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith, 

 (SELECT ith.ItemCode, SUM(ith.TransactionQty) AS total
  FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith
  WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
  AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
  AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
  GROUP BY ith.ItemCode
 ) AS TEST1,

 (SELECT ith.ItemCode, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 0_90_Days
  FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith
  WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
  AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
  AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
  GROUP BY ith.ItemCode
  ) AS TEST2,

 (SELECT ith.ItemCode, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 91_180_Days
  FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith
  WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
  AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
  AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
  GROUP BY ith.ItemCode
  ) AS TEST3,

 (SELECT ith.ItemCode, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 181 AND 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS 181_270_Days
  FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith
  WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
  AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
  AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
  GROUP BY ith.ItemCode
  ) AS TEST4,

 (SELECT ith.ItemCode, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ith.TransactionDate) > 270 THEN ith.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) AS Over_270_Days
  FROM im_itemtransactionhistory ith
  WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
  AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
  AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
  GROUP BY ith.ItemCode
  ) AS TEST5


WHERE ith.TransactionCode = 'PO'
AND ith.TransactionDate >= '2018-01-01'
AND ith.ItemCode = 512619
AND ith.ItemCode = TEST1.ItemCode
AND ith.ItemCode = TEST2.ItemCode

GROUP BY ith.ItemCode, TEST2.0_90_Days, TEST3.91_180_Days, TEST4.181_270_Days, TEST5.Over_270_Days
```

And posting the results hope this helps someone with same problems.

```
+----------+-------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| ItemCode | total | 0_90_Days | 91_180_Days | 181_270_Days | Over_270_Days |
+----------+-------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|   512619 | 19692 |      4692 |       13800 |         1200 |             0 |
+----------+-------+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```